# Jar compatibility with all JRE Version

Tags: java, jar

My applet application compiles at JRE 7 and created signed jar. I deployed .jar file at my client machine. But I got  exception i.e.,"Unsupported major.minor version 51.0" at IE. I want provide an applet jar file to compatibility all browsers. How to make compatibility a jar file?

Comment: "all browsers any JRE" is a fools errand. There's no value and way too much bother in supporting Java 1.3 or earlier, and personally I wouldn't bother with anything before 1.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to compile your application using an older JDK. I guess that is the only way you will directly see that you are using the correct JDK API available on older JREs and also dependencies (3rd party JAR files on the classpath) in the correct binary version usable on the older JRE/JDK. Go as far as you need, i.e. use the JDK in version 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, or 1.6.

If the library is not available for older JRE version, you will need to somehow back-port it (and possibly its transitive dependencies too). This may get quite tricky and may involve a lot of effort (using tools such as RetroWeaver or similar). So make your backward compatibility choice very carefully.

Comment: Guess, the question targets the jar file, where the answer might be, that each class file is versioned by the compiler and so the version by protocol not a property of the jar file.

Answer (score 2):

Compile your source files to a lower target version - specifically, the target JVM version you want to support, using the `-source` and  `-target` flags in `javac`.

So, for instance:

```
javac -source 5 -target 5 -sourcepath /path/to/code -d /path/to/compiled/code *.java
```

Comment: Also a good idea would be using some sort of API checker to make sure the app only uses libraries available in whichever JDK.

Comment: Why not just use the older JDK to compile with?  Then you know it cannot be using libraries that were not available in that version.

Comment: The compiler is backwards compatible.  Why do we need to get an older compiler to use functionality that was intentionally baked in?

Comment: @Makoto by all means use the compiler from Java 7, but if you want to know your code will work on Java 5 then you need to [set the bootclasspath](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/bootclasspath_older_source) to point to a Java 5 version of rt.jar as well as setting `-source` and `-target`.  If you don't do this then you're compiling against the Java 7 class library, and things like `if(someString.isEmpty())` will compile successfully but then fail with a NoSuchMethodError when run on Java 5.